# Object class has been removed in cakephp3

Tags: php, object, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am beginner with cakephp 3
I read that 'The object class has been removed' in this [link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html)

What does this really mean as i have read many references to objects in the documentation further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your refer to is the migration guide to CakePHP 3.x. Object class (with a big O) was a class used in a previous version of CakePHP. This class was a "holdall" bag of methods used across the Framework. However this class no longer exists.